# Results Commands in SUMO

Tags: sumo

I am running traffic lights scenarios in SUMO and i want to get results.
My question is how to get results by using commands?

```
e.g --queue-output <FILE>.
```

I have tried running it like net convert and poly convert commands but i do not know what should i add it with `--queue-output stats.XML` because i am getting error in command line.

Comment: Please post your error message then. It should be as simple as running `sumo -n mynet.net.xml -r myroutes.rou.xml --queue-output stats.xml`.

Comment: @Michael how can i get the average of generated output ??

Comment: Please do not use StackOverflow for discussions. We have a mailing list, see http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Contact. You might also want to check http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Xml for how to convert your output to csv and use it in a spreadsheet application.